# Unable update the @State variable in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I hava a variable named index that decorated @State, and I want update value when click setting toolbar button.

The toolbar button's block is executed, but the value of index still is -1.

I debug and check out the value of currentIndex, it still is -1.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State var isPresentingAddView = false
    @State var index = -1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack() {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("title"))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        index = 1
                        isPresentingAddView = true
                    } label: {
                        Label("setting", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingAddView) {
            let currentIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

The toolbar button block code is execute before the sheet block code

Comment: Use sheet(item:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't read `index` in `body` anywhere yet so the dependency wasn't set up, usually you will add code to read it eventually but the in the meantime you can just do:

```
NavigationStack { [index] in
```

The preferred way though. is to use a different sheet modifier, that uses a custom value instead of a bool, then you don't need the bool at all, e.g.

```
    @State var index: Int?
...
 .sheet(item: $index) { value in
            let currentIndex = value
        }
```

Another example is in the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)

Comment: I use this way, and xcode has error "sheet requires that 'Int' conform to 'Identifiable'.".  I change index var to object var that conform to 'Identifiable', the problem is solved. Thanks.